# C++ char sequence function always return empty string

Tags: c++, charsequence

Just start learning C++ and trying to make a simple function that do substring with following code:

```
char* substring(int start, int end, const char* target)
{
    size_t length = strlen(target);

    char result[(length + 1)];

    int iterator = 0;

    for(int i = start; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(i <= end)
        {
            result[iterator] = target[i];

            iterator++;
        }
    }

    result[iterator] = '\0';

    cout << result << endl; // This give correct result "aya";

    return result;
}
```

When I use these function on main method:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char some_text[] = "Saya Makan";

    char* sub = substring(1, 3, some_text); // No string returned

    cout << "Substring Result is: " << sub;

    return 0;
}
```

It give output is like this:

```
aya
Substring Result is: 
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 44ms)
```

As seen on the result, my function isn't returning anything but empty string although a line of code before return, the "result" variable echoed result correctly. Would you please explain to me what is happening inside my function, am I missing something?

Comment: Looks more like C than C++ (the problem is that you're returning a pointer to a local variable which undefined behavior)

Comment: What make it more like C than C++? Is it because i use char* rather than std::string?

Comment: Yes. Ideally you should use `std::string`, but since you're learning it's okay to use `char*`. You should also use things like `std::copy` instead of that `for` loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you very much for your advice Sir. It took so much time for me to figure out what is exactly this char sequence things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning pointer to a local array which is not required to live beyond the function.

You need to make the buffer persist beyond the scope of the function by allocating it dynamically using `malloc`. And ofcourse remember to `free` it later.

Oh just noticed its C++.
So drop the idea of `malloc` and `free` simply use `std::string` and not `char *`.

Comment: Rather than `malloc`, just pass a pointer to a string buffer which you will write into.

Comment: Thanks. But is it better to use std::string than char sequence? What will you recommend me to use? Char sequence or std::string? I really need advice about this.

Comment: @yunhasnawa: Use `std::string`, it saves you all the problems of manual memory management which come with using `char *` and provides u everything that a `char *` provides u.